# Hosted streaming server

Tags: video-streaming

I do have some videos which needs to be played in schedule like a TV. The stream will be published in iOS and Android devices via native app. I need to know some easy to use hosting provider who can help me on this with a easy to upload the videos and schedule.

-Souvik

Answer (score 0):

A hoster like this does not exist as far as i know. There are hosters who provide the basic infrastructure for what u are trying to archieve though. There are opensource solution like Red5 or paid options like Wowza and Adobe Media Server.